# Why do I have slow download speed on my system upgrades?

Tags: 11.04, system, downloads

I have very slow download speed when I do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
I have natty 11.04, I upgraded from 10.10 to the beta.
The speed is down at b/s and not at the normal kb/s (note not kbit/s).

```
Fetched 2,621 B in 19s (133 B/s)

Fetched 2,621 B in 20s (129 B/s)
```

Why do I have the slow download speed?

Can I fix it in any way?

Comment: Have you tried changing to a different mirror? Update Manager > Settings > Ubuntu Software > Download From

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a mirror that's closer to you.  Here's a list: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: I sometimes find that the UK mirrors are slow and that updating from the US main server is faster..then sometimes not :)

Comment: I changed to a swedish server, and now I'm downloading at 1.0mbps

Comment: The us.ubuntu archive mirrors have always been quite slow for me, and for whatever reason, the repos that come baked-in with Canonicals EC2 AMIs only seem to get about 20kB/s.  I typically switch to the mirror that a local ISP (Xmission) provides.  I can get my packages at line speed from those guys - bliss!